# how to share large object in multiprocess？

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I want to do large calculation in python.
and I want to use multiprocess to do it.
The problem is that I must transport large obj(such as large numpy and list,or list of numpy), from main process to the process created by main process

Here is the problem:
1. if I use like `results[i] = pool.apply_async(func, args_tuple)` then it will try to pickle the args_tuple ,which cost large time
2. my own class and numpy class is not supported
3. all the object has been prepared in the main process, if I get it in the generated process ,it will cost time also.

How could I solve this problem.. Maybe I should use java if I had predicted this, I looked it up in the doc, but it seems that every solution is the same -- pickle the params from main process to others (cost time)

Answer (score 0):

**As far as I know**, every way of communicating between process use pickle to transfer the data (`Pipes`, `Queue` and others...)

One way to make your issue work could be to work on shared variables, but you can't work on the same object with multiples process at the same time so it depends on your application.
Their is some simple implemented shared variables in multiprocessing : `Array` and `Value` which are respectively a 1D array and a single value (int, float, str...). [See the documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

But you can also create your own types if you need to, using `ctype` : [see the documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects)

Comment: I have another idea: start serveral processes when the whole program start up , and if I have task ,the main process while call other processes, if I do not have task ,the ohter processes will sleep .

Comment: But I do not know how to create processes which are waiting for the main process, and how to notify and return . where can I find the doc? or I can search what to do this?

Comment: You should start looking at the Global Interpreter Lock to understand the issues in multiprocessing.